# Clique of constant size

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

It is well known that Clique is a NP-Complete problem, But given some constant value K, finding whether a graph G has a clique of size K, is always a log-space (L) class problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For any *fixed* $k$, you can enumerate all of the $k$-element subsets in logarithmic space, and check whether each of them is a clique.